# sqlalchemy query on deleted object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I recently write a client testing program to test my server.  In the test, I start using orm to delete existing objects (row) in the database.  Then I send in a sequence of commands to the server to recreate the data.  But when I try to query the "deleted" objects in the test program, the query will return no object found unless I query with a session with another "name".  I will have concern on how session work in SqlAlchemy and not sure if this is a bug.  The following will further illustrate the problem.

```
engine  = create_engine("mysql:....")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for registration in session.query(Registration).filter_by(license_id = id).all():
    session.delete(registration)
    session.commit()
```

.... codes to send command to the server which will create some rows in the registration table in the database ....

```
x = session.query(Registration).filter_by(license_id = id).all()
print x
```

x will be an empty list.

I try add the following before query the second time and all return the same result

```
session.close()
session = Session()
```

or

```
session.expunge_all()
```

or

```
session.exipre_all()
```

None of the above work until I do the following

```
new_session = Session()
x = new_session.query(Registration).filter_by(license_id = id).all()
```

This time, x return what stored in the database.

I am kind of confuse why I need to changed the session variable name in order to work.  All document in related to session such as session.expire, session.expunge, or even getting another instance of session (with the same name but is different instance, I have checked), does not work.

Appreciate if anyone can help.  Thanks.

The full code

```
import socket
import blowfish
import base64
import string
import sys
import logging
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, and_
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Date, Boolean, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

from lrp_modal import User, Product, License, Registration

log = logging.getLogger('')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

def test(token, passwd, xmsg, expect_ok):
    serverHost = 'localhost'
    serverPort = 9120

    sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
    data = sockobj.recv(1024)
    log.debug('Client received: %s', repr(data))

    log.debug("Send: %s",  xmsg)
    sockobj.send(xmsg)

    x = ''
    while 1:
        data = sockobj.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        x += data
    x = x.strip()
    log.debug("Receive: %s", x)
    if expect_ok and not x.startswith('<lrp'):
        print "Test fail"
        sys.exit(1)
    if not expect_ok and x.startswith('<lrp'):
        print "Test fail"
        sys.exit(1)

master   = 'X01X-0000-0000-'
liclist  = {
    'product60_tri': ['0001'],
    'product60_pro': ['0002'],
    'product50_ent': ['0003', '0004', '0005'],
    'product60_ent': ['0006', '0007', '0008'],
    }

machines = ['FFBCC89220EF', '00112233']

# Setup the licenses testing data
engine  = create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1/padsystem')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for tag, idlist in liclist.items():
    for id in idlist:
        product = session.query(Product).filter_by(product_tag = tag).one()
        try:
            license = session.query(License).filter_by(license_id = master + id).one()
        except NoResultFound:
            continue

        license.product_id = product.product_id
        license.act_rid  = ''
        license.act_type = ''
        license.act_hint = ''
        license.group_id = ''
        if id == '0003':
            license.lic_expire = date(2011, 1, 1)
            if id in ('0001', '0006'):
                license.lic_expire = date.today() + timedelta(10)
        if id in ('0004', '0005', '0007', '0008'):
            license.group_id = 'X'
        session.commit()

        for registration in session.query(Registration).filter_by(license_id = license.license_id).all():
            session.delete(registration)
        session.commit()

user    = session.query(User).get(1)

# Test to register a machine
log.info('Test register machine...')
data = """<lrp service="register">
    <registration>
      <product>Product50</product>
      <license>%s</license>
      <machine>%s</machine>
    </registration>
  </lrp>
  """
for id in ('0004', '0006', '0007'):
    lic_id = master + id
    test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, data % (lic_id, machines[0]), True)
    test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, data % (lic_id, machines[1]), True)

for id in ('0001', '0003'):
    lic_id = master + id
    test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, data % (lic_id, machines[0]), False)

# Test to register a machine until register count is full.
lic_id = master + '0002'
for i in range(5):
    log.info("Register count test %s ", i)
    x = data % (lic_id, machines[1] + str(i))
    test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, x, True)

log.info("Register exceed max...")
x = data % (lic_id, machines[0])
test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, x, False)

# Test register to group of licenses
lic_id = master + '0008'
for i in range(8):
    log.info("Register group count test: %s ", i)
    x = data % (lic_id, machines[1] + str(i))
    test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, x, True)

log.info("Register exceed group max...")
x = data % (lic_id, machines[0])
test('LICENSEE %s\n' % user.user_name, user.password, x, False)

# Test to unregister
data = """<lrp service="unregister">
    <registration id="%s">
      <product>Product50</product>
      <license>%s</license>
      <machine>%s</machine>
    </registration>
  </lrp>
  """

# session.expunge_all()  not work
# session.expire_all()   not work
# session.close(); del(session); session = Session()  not work
new_session = Session()  # This is needed, cannot use session!!
lic_id = master + '0004'
# Use original session instance will get null list.
for r in new_session.query(Registration).filter_by(license_id = lic_id).all():
    rid = r.rid
    mid = r.machine_id
    log.info("Unregister, wrong license...")
    x = data % (rid, master + '0005', mid)
    test('REGISTER %s\n' % rid, mid, x, False)
    log.info("Unregister...")
    x = data % (rid, lic_id, mid) 
    test('REGISTER %s\n' % rid, mid, x, True)
```

Comment: Please, include all the code relevant to reproduce your problem. It's hard to give a correct answer without knowing how exactly you are recreating the objects after deleting.

Comment: are you sure that the `license_id` value is actually the same in both cases?

Comment: The code is basically the same in the above except between the for loop and the "x = " statement, there is a lot of test() which is a function to do testing.  It work as soon as I rename the session variable to new_session.  Nothing else changed.  I shall post the code below.